# Drop all variables that are empty

Tags: stata

After importing an Excel file into Stata, some empty columns are imported as empty variables.

Example data:

```
set obs 10
generate A = 1
generate B = .
```

I want to drop variables like `B`. Of course, in my real data, there are lots of variables so I want to do it intelligently rather than manually.

I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
foreach var of varlist * {
    capture confirm string variable `var'
    if _rc {
        generate `var'check=1 if `var'==.
        egen total_`var'check=total(`var'check)
        drop `var' if total_`var'check==.
    }
}
```

Comment: So, every time you check a numeric variable for suitability to -drop- you create two more? Otherwise the first bug here I see is that if all values are numeric missing, then the total of your check variable won’t be missing, but the same as the number of observations. Also your -if- qualifier in the last line needs to be an -if- command. @Pearly gives one better approach. Another is to -count- missing values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
foreach var of varlist * {
    capture assert missing(`var')
    if !_rc drop `var'
}
```

Alternatively, the *community-contributed* command `missings` can do this in one line.